# Triggering click event from URL

Tags: jquery

I am building a FAQ page, and am needing help with the second part of my jquery function. 
When you click on a question, it shows the answer. 
What I am also wanting to do is when i link to an anchor, to also show the answer to the question.

**Script:**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.faq-title').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.faq-content').slideToggle('fast');
    })
var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('.faq-title').find('a[href*='+ hash + ']').closest('h4').trigger('click');
})
```

**Html:**

```
<div class="faq">
    <h4 class="faq-title" style="cursor:pointer;padding:0 0 6px 0;"><a id="q1"></a>1. <span style="text-decoration:underline;">Question</span></h4>
    <div class="faq-content" style="display:none;"><p style="color: #808080;">Answer</p></div>
</div>
<div class="faq">
    <h4 class="faq-title" style="cursor:pointer;padding:0 0 6px 0;"><a id="q2"></a>2. <span style="text-decoration:underline;">Question</span></h4>
    <div class="faq-content" style="display:none;"><p style="color: #808080;">Answer</p></div>
</div>
<div class="faq">
    <h4 class="faq-title" style="cursor:pointer;padding:0 0 6px 0;"><a id="q3"></a>3. <span style="text-decoration:underline;">Question</span></h4>
    <div class="faq-content" style="display:none;"><p style="color: #808080;">Answer</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `link to an anchor `?

Comment: When you use a hash URL modifier to link to a particular piece of content on a page. for example: www.url.com/page.html#q3 would like to the third question.

Comment: Well then go check on page load, whether there is a hash part in the URL – and if so, trigger your code that shows the corresponding answer.

Comment: Got it working using a combination of answers. HTML stays as is, updated the script to:
`jQuery(function($) {
        $('.faq-title').click(function () {
            $(this).siblings('.faq-content').slideToggle('fast');
        })
    var hash = location.hash;
        $('.faq-title').find(hash).closest('h4').trigger('click');
    })`
Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your javascript:

```
.find(hash)
```

Check [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/hoqid/2/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: `window.location.hash` already has a hash when you [call it](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp)

Comment: This worked, I also had to change the `window.location.hash` to just `location.hash`

Answer (score 0):

I added CSS to clean up the HTML. Basically, just check whether there is a hash (e.g., `#q3`), and, if there is, trigger the event handler attached to it. In this case, click `#q3`.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/8efjK/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="faq">
    <h4 class="faq-title">
        <a id="q1"></a>1. <span>Question</span>
    </h4>
    <div class="faq-content">
        <p>Answer</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="faq">
    <h4 class="faq-title">
        <a id="q1"></a>2. <span>Question</span>
    </h4>
    <div class="faq-content">
        <p>Answer</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="faq">
    <h4 class="faq-title">
        <a id="q1"></a>3. <span>Question</span>
    </h4>
    <div class="faq-content">
        <p>Answer</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
h4.faq-title {
    cursor: points;
    padding: 0 0 6px 0;
}
span {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
p {
    color: #808080;
}
div.faq-content {
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash) {
        $(hash).closest("h4").trigger("click");
    }
    $('.faq-title').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.faq-content').slideToggle('fast');
    })
})
```